# How to get attribute of Object that inside list of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone guide me how to extract the attribute of object that is inside a list of list. For example, I got:

```
class Symbol:
    def __init__(self, name, mtype, value = None):
        self.name = name
        self.mtype = mtype
        self.value = value


# ... some more code
```

Then after running some code, I will get list of variable such as:

```
list_var = [Symbol(varname_1, vartype_1), Symbol(varname_2, vartype_2), ..., Symbol(varname_n, vartype_n)]
```

So, I would like to get only the vartype as the list of vartype i.e

```
list(vartype_1,...vartype_n)
```

Comment: use `[obj.mtype for obj in list_var]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use `map`:

```
n_lst = list(map(lambda x: x.mtype,list_var))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the attribute of any object by doing `object.attribute`, or in your case `Symbol().mtype`

The fact that it's in a list makes no difference. Iterate over the list and grab the attribute for each element:

```
n_lst = [symbol.mtype for symbol in list_var]
```